# axios ECONNREFUSED when requesting in a docker-compose service behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, axios, create-react-app

I have two docker-compose setup, the main service is an SPA containing:

- nginx proxy for a wordpress on port 80
- wordpress + mysql
- expressjs for serving a react app port 6000

This runs behind another docker-compose which is basically an nginx-reverse proxy.

The SPA manages to serve website and connects to backend API via reverse proxy just fine. However, when I try to make a separate https request to the backend api from the server.js I get this message:

    `{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1121:14)
      errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 443 }`

And it's not just axios, plain wget to the backend url gives me connection refused as well.
A sample for said request:

`` axios.put('/wc/v3/orders/934', {
      status: "completed"
    },{
      withCredentials:true,
      auth: {
        username: process.env.REACT_APP_WC_ADMIN_CK_KEY,
        password: process.env.REACT_APP_WC_ADMIN_CS_KEY
      }
    }).then(function (response) {
         console.log(`ok`);
      }).catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
      }); ``

Any one knows what might be the problem here?

Comment: have you configured nginx to listen on 443 ? is it actually listen on 443 or not ?

Comment: @MostafaHussein I think it's listening on 443 though since I can access https app just fine on my browser. I was suspicious of the same thing and tried http as well but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple docker-compose environments, then each brings up its own network by default. You want to [share the network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks) between the two to allow for the services in one environment to communicate to the other.

```
# spa/docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  spa:
    ...
    networks:
      - app-net
networks:
  app-net:
    driver: bridge
```

.

```
# express/docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  api:
    ...
    networks:
      - spa_app-net
networks:
  spa_app-net:
    external: true
```

Comment: That's already been done. I'm using docker version 3.3 though and the config is
networks: default: external: name: proxy
Since the frontend and wordpress is communicating between each other just fine, I think it's already working correctly?

Comment: Please show us your docker-compose and/or dockerfile(s). Your SPA is making the requests from the host to the ports exposed by the container. But I am not sure both your backend containers can see each other.